# Find the number of sequences of letters: ’AAABBBCCC’ such that:

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

a)Three identical letters are not next to each other.
So I came up with a solution but I have no possibility to check whether it's correct so I've decided to post it here.
So *|X|* - number of all possible sequences,
 |X| = $\frac{9!}{3!\cdot 3!\cdot 3!}$
 |A|, |B| and |C| are those sequences in which either 3 A's, B's or C's are next to each other
|A| = |B| = |C| = $7\cdot \binom{6}{3}\cdot \binom{3}{3}= 140$
$|A\cap B|, |A\cap C|  ,|B\cap C|$  are for use of Inclusion-exclusion
$|A\cap B|=|A\cap C|=|B\cap C|=7\cdot 4\cdot \binom{3}{3}= 28$
$|A\cap B\cap C|=1$
$|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|$
And the number we're looking for $=|X|-|A\cup B\cup C|$
Is that by any chance a correct solution?

Comment: I think you have mistake in $A \cup B$ it is actually 20

Comment: @lulu looked for it, couldn't find it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is good. Two mistakes I can see:

In $A \cap B$, I'm not sure where your $7$ comes from. I'd do it this way: we have $5$ things to arrange: the $A$ block, the $B$ block, and three $C$s. Choose one slot for the $A$ block ($5$ choices) and one for the $B$ block ($4$ choices), and the rest are $C$s. So it should be $20$.

In $A \cap B \cap C$, you have to order the $3$ blocks, so it should be $3!$, not $1$

Answer (score 0):

Only mistake is in $\mid {A \cup B}\mid$ it is $5!\over {3!}$

Comment: Did you mean $|A \cap B|$? and if yes, then where does this result come from?